# Why doesn't recursion work in leetcode question?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, recursion

I am trying to solve a simple question by using recursion.

**Given a non-negative integer num, return the number of steps to reduce it to zero. If the current number is even, you have to divide it by 2, otherwise, you have to subtract 1 from it.**

I have given my solution as:

```
class Solution:
    def numberOfSteps(self, num: int) -> int:
            if num!=0:
                if num%2==0:
                    return 1+ numberOfSteps(num//2)
                else:
                    return 1+ numberOfSteps(num-1)
            else:
                return 0
```

However i am encountering this error:

```
NameError: name 'numberOfSteps' is not defined
    return 1+ numberOfSteps(num//2)
Line 5 in numberOfSteps (Solution.py)
    ret = Solution().numberOfSteps (param_1)
Line 29 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 40 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

Comment: You need to use `self.numberOfSteps` in place of `numberOfSteps` when you call it.

Comment: Do you really have to put this in a class?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I suspect that the Leetcode website requires it.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille that is how it is in leetcode, you cant change the function declaration

Comment: @ArnavBagchi You have another problem in your code. When the number is 0, there are 0 steps required. Why are you returning 1 in that case?

Comment: @alaniwi i rectified that issue it should be ```return 0```

Comment: @ArnavBagchi Alternative solution: `b = bin(num)[2:]; return len(b) + b.count('1') - 1` -- I'll leave you to work out why this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Solution:
    def numberOfSteps(self, num: int) -> int:
            if num!=0:
                if num%2==0:
                    return 1+ self.numberOfSteps(num//2)
                else:
                    return 1+ self.numberOfSteps(num-1)
            else:
                return 1
```